# Visual Studio 2015 find/replace entire class with regular expression

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2015

I have an inner class inside every controller of my project like that

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        ... //lots of code in multiple lines
    }
```

Its missing a **}**, so I want to add that on all ~500 files. 
Tried some regular expression on VS2015, but without success, like that:

```
MyClass[\t]*(.*\n)*\\}
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: It is not... It was an initial complex replace to add that class.

Comment: Is `MyClass` at the end of the files?

Comment: Could you share the whole template? (signatures and braces)

Comment: What you mean by template?  They are MVC controllers and dont follow a fixed signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your snippet is always the same length, you can use this regex:

```
(public class myclass\n(?:^.*$\n){x})
                                  ^replace with the number of lines.
```

and replace with `\1}` see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gT6eB9/1)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not the case